# What planets would I be able to see in the sky I were standing on the battlefield of Hoth?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, battle-of-hoth, hoth

As the title says, If I were standing in the spot where the battle of Hoth took place in *The Empire Strikes Back* and I looked upwards, what planets would I be able to see in the sky?

Comment: I doubt this is explicitly answered in any canon sources.

Comment: Alright fair enough! Ty

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Probably two venus-sized points of light (Jhas and Ordaj) in addition to the local star (also named Hoth).

According to *The Empire Strikes Back*, Hoth was the sixth planet in the system which means that there's the potential for five (or fewer, or possibly more) additional objects in the sky aside from the weak local sun.

> “My lord,” the general replied, choosing each word with care, “the
>   fleet has moved out of light-speed. Com-Scan has detected an energy
>   field protecting an area of the sixth planet in the Hoth system. The
>   field is strong enough to deflect any bombardment.”

We also know from the game [Star Wars: Uprising](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Uprising) that there were two gas giant planets in the Hoth System, one named Jhas and another unnamed one (named as Ordaj in the Legends *[Essential Atlas](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas)*). From the ground it seems likely that those would be visible at the very least.

[image]

Comment: They would likely be visible as bright points of light in the sky at various times depending on where on Hoth you were and where those planets  happened to be at the moment as they and planet Hoth circled around the star Hoth at different speeds.

Comment: @M.A. Golding - Indeed, and if they were ruddy (like the one in the picture) or black, they might be all but invisible, hence *"probably"*